# Translating to ruby for use in rubymotion

Tags: objective-c, ruby

Here is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:     (NSUInteger)glyphIndex withProposedLineFragmentRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return 20; 
}
```

Comment: Good for you that you got your answer, but Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: Well it's not just translation that he's asking for. I'm sure he wants to understand what's not working for him.

Comment: @Neil Slater so, where should I take my translation requests next time?

Comment: @Abdo yes, am trying to set line height for a paragraph within a textview

Comment: @Sherwyn Goh: On Stack Overflow, ideally you should explain your problem in a way that makes it useful for someone else to find and use later. "Translate this code" has no value to anyone but you. So if you rephrased the question to "How do I set the line height for a paragraph", tagged appropriately and showed a little of the existing Ruby code then this would be a much better question. Then it would be OK to say "I know this is the correct Objective-C, but don't understand how to translate it"

Comment: gotcha! Will rephrase next time. I didn't ask this time in an attempt to figure it out on my own

Answer (score 1):

```
def layoutManager(layoutManager, lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:glyphIndex withProposedLineFragmentRect:rect)
  20
end
```

Start here: http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Already went through that, and the book. Not that helpful, iOS still confuses me since I only have a rails background

Comment: I can understand, I also went through that... But the few examples on this page give you the syntax to translate Objective-C method into Ruby.See the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` example.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
def layoutManager(layoutManager, lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex: nil, withProposedLineFragmentRect: nil)
    return 20.0
end
```

Check [the repo](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples) for examples.
Also, that method should return a float, not an int.